# connect to read replica of Azure SQL database Hyper Scale

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-sql-database

I have an Azure SQL Database in the Hyper Scale service level with one secondary replica.  I have  been trying to prove that the ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly is actually going to the secondary replica.  So I created this PowerShell script:

---

```
$FQTargetServer = "server.database.windows.net"
$SqlServerPort = 1433
$Database = "database"
$SqlUsername = "user"
$SqlPass = "**********"
$command = ""
$dataset = ""

$Conn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Server=tcp:$FQTargetServer,$SqlServerPort;Database=$Database;ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly;User ID=$SqlUsername;Password=$SqlPass") 

$Conn.Open() 

$command = new-object system.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(
        "SELECT DB_NAME() as 'db',DATABASEPROPERTYEX(DB_NAME(), 'Updateability') as 'replica';", $Conn)
    $command.CommandTimeout=1200
    $command.CommandText 

# Execute the SQL command 
$dataset=New-Object system.Data.DataSet 
$adapter=New-Object system.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter $command
write-output $adapter.Fill($dataSet) | Out-Null

# Close the SQL connection 
$Conn.Close()
$dataset.Tables
```

---

The results I get are:
db         replica

---

database READ_WRITE

This indicates to me that the ApplicationIntent is being ignored for some reason.  Any ideas on how to connect to the read-only replica?

Thank you,
Dep

Answer (score 0):

When we want to connect to the read-only replica, we must add the `ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly;` to the connection string.

For example, the following connection string connects the client to a read-only replica:

```
Server=tcp:<server>.database.windows.net;Database=<mydatabase>;ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly;User ID=<myLogin>;Password=<myPassword>;Trusted_Connection=False; Encrypt=True;
```

Please ref: [Connect to a read-only replica](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/read-scale-out#connect-to-a-read-only-replica)

And for another reason, we must enable the read scale-out which we could get from the document:

- If you wish to ensure that the application connects to the primary
  replica regardless of the ApplicationIntent setting in the SQL
  connection string, you must explicitly disable read scale-out when
  creating the database or when altering its configuration. For
  example, if you upgrade your database from Standard or General
  Purpose tier to Premium, Business Critical or Hyperscale tier and
  want to make sure all your connections continue to go to the primary
  replica, disable read scale-out. For details on how to disable it,
  see [Enable and disable read scale-out](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/read-scale-out#enable-and-disable-read-scale-out).

Another ref: [Specifying Application Intent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client/features/sql-server-native-client-support-for-high-availability-disaster-recovery?view=sql-server-ver15#specifying-application-intent)

Comment: I believe that is what this line in the script says:  Server=tcp:$FQTargetServer,$SqlServerPort;Database=$Database;ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly;User ID=$SqlUsername;Password=$SqlPass". That is why I am confused why the DATABASEPROPERTYEX(DB_NAME(), 'Updateability') id coming back read-write.

Comment: @Dep Sorry for missing that. Did you enable the read scale-out for your SQL database?

Comment: @LeonYue Did you connect to the read-only replica?